# Alternatives to document.title?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, document

I'm attempting to return the page title. Using document.title doesn't appear to be reliable. It's often returning the title of frames within a page and sometimes nothing depending on the web page. I'd like to return the title which appears at the top of the tab e.g `Gmail - Inbox etc..` on a Gmail page. Is there any alternatives to document.title? I'm testing on Chrome.

Comment: You mean in a browser extension? Not sure I understand the GMail part otherwise. I doubt you will be able to get the title of documents that don't belong to you.

Comment: The Gmail one was just as example of an AJAX page giving me issues by not returning anything. Other pages returning the Twitter button on their pages .title. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is with frames. You could try `top.document.title`, which will give you the title of the topmost frame.